# Can SQL query lost due to hard disk crash be recovered?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have ran a SQL query joining many base tables in various steps as #Tables and final output (Which is a separate table). My hard disk is crashed. I Have run this query 4 days back. I ran it from my local system by SQL management studio connecting to the server. Now I'm having the base tables and the output table as tables in SQL but I have lost the query which I have used to arrive at my final table due to hard drive crash. Can that query which I ran from my local system SQL management studio 4 days back be recovered from logs or by any other means? It was one of the last few queries which I tried in that database in that server.

Comment: You might be lucky... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/grahamk/archive/2009/09/24/sql-server-dmv-script-for-searching-the-plan-cache-by-query-text-plan-handle-or-execution-time.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], execsql.text AS [Script] 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC
```

Or in one of these locations depending on OS.

```
C:\Windows\System32\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files\Solution1

C:\Users\YourUsername\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files
```